# Using Mongoose Rather than the MongoDB Driver to Find Document

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

We are in the process of writing tests for our Node/MongoDB backend and I have a question about finding documents.

My understanding is it's preferable to use Mongoose to get your documents as opposed to the MongoDB driver. In other words, doing `Customer.findOne().exec()` instead of setting up a db connection and then doing `db.collection("customers").findOne()`.

Other than the first option (using Mongoose to find the doc) being slightly less verbose, I'm curious what the other reasons are. Is a straight MongoDB lookup a bigger drag on the database?

Answer (score 1):

One of the great feature of mongoose is the built in validation mechanism. Also the **Populate** method to get data from multiple collections is an awesome characteristic of Mongoose. 
In terms of query performance, here is a good read:

https://medium.com/@bugwheels94/performance-difference-in-mongoose-vs-mongodb-60be831c69ad

Hope this helps :)

Comment: I agree that in many cases Mongoose is the better option, for just those reasons. I'm aware of those. But I'm also curious for a simple find - where nothing else is needed - if one is superior to the other, and why.

Comment: i think your answer is answered in the link.. Did you check that?

Comment: My question was more about if one is recommended more than the other in various situations. For instance, for testing, one could argue that a call via the MongoDB driver is more low level than using Mongoose, which goes through the models. So in this case, is there any reason not to use the MongoDB driver? Or is Mongoose a good idea even here?